# Add newlines to label-displays in `showkeys` package

Tags: labels, showlabels, showkeys

I'm using the package [showkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/showkeys) to display labels in my LaTeX file. All my labels are of the form `type:name:details`. Since my labels tend to get very long (`lemma:the_name_of_the_lemma:...`) I'd like to redefine the `\showkeyslabelformat` command to break the line at every `:`.

How is this possible? Is there a way to replace the `:` by newlines?

Answer (score 5):

showkeys uses the following command to typeset the label

```
\providecommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{%
  \fbox{\normalfont\small\ttfamily#1}}
```

so you can redefine that in any way you want,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showkeys}

\renewcommand*\showkeyslabelformat[1]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\raggedright\normalfont\small\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=`\:#1}}}

\begin{document}

\section{zzz\label{section:with:a:long:label}}
\begin{equation}
  \label{equation:with:an:even:longer:label}
  1=0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought to get an answer from the actual author of the package. Is there by any chance a way to get the content of the boxed right-aligned/left-aligned depending of the position of the box (left/right)? I would like to have the content of the left boxes right-aligned, and the context of the right boxed left-aligned.

Comment: not without changing quite a bit see the line `\gdef\SK@lab{\smash{\SK@labelcolor\showkeyslabelformat{#2}}}%` the label is just set once into a box which is then used in several cases, so you would need to save a left adjusted box and a right adjusted box then everywhere `\SK@lab` is used change it to use one or the other. A lot of effort for a simple debugging package.

Comment: Ok, thank you for looking into it. I'll just go with your answer!

Comment: I only use labels for equation and definitions and lemmas. Therefore only equations are placed on the right side of the sheet. Since all of my equation labels start with `eq` I was thinking about using `xstring` to make a case distinction `\renewcommand{\showkeyslabelformat}[1]{\IfBeginWith{#1}{eq}{RIGHT}{LEFT}}`. Sadly, the condition does not seem to work. Do you see why this could be the case?

Answer (score 2):

Ooooh, I was just about to answer and say this was hard (because catcodes), when David replied with a solution using `\hyphenchar`.  Cunning!

So I'll simply chip in by remarking that the exact same command works in [showlabels](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/showlabels), with only a change of name.

```
\renewcommand*\showlabelsetlabel[1]{%
  \fbox{\parbox[t]{2cm}{%
    \raggedright\normalfont\small\ttfamily
    \hyphenchar\font=`\:
    #1}}}
```

Comment: Thanks! This will most definitely help future readers using `showlabels`.